# The DOM is not rendering what it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS:

```
function climat(code, isday, hour){
    weather = {'113': (isday == "yes" && hour < 4) ? '<i class="sunn"></i>' : '<i class="moonn"></i>'   }
    return weather[code]
};

function Meteo(d) {
    for (h = 1; h < 4; h++) {
        alert(climat(meteo[d].hourly[h].weatherCode, meteo[d].hourly[h].isdaytime, h));
        $("#meteo"+h).html(climat(meteo[d].hourly[h].weatherCode, meteo[d].hourly[h].isdaytime), h)
    }
};
```

Now, I dont get what it should, I used for this the `alert()` and the tenary is ok, so what happens?

Here is test from the console:

```
 meteo = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meteo')).data.weather
 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 climat(meteo[3].hourly[2].weatherCode, meteo[3].hourly[2].isdaytime, 5)
 "<i class="moonn"></i>"
 climat(meteo[3].hourly[2].weatherCode, meteo[3].hourly[2].isdaytime, 4)
 "<i class="moonn"></i>"
 climat(meteo[3].hourly[2].weatherCode, meteo[3].hourly[2].isdaytime, 3)
 "<i class="sunn"></i>"
```

Here is a screenshot, the class called is `sunn`, but it renders `moonn`:

[image]

Comment: @DavidThomas sorry, i pasted an extra `{` that comes from the main function `function Meteo(d) {`

Comment: Simple typo: The `h` argument isn't inside the argument list of the `climat()` function call.

Comment: @Barmar awww! i should change my IDE preferences :D thank you! you just saved my night! can you please write it as answer so i can validate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$("#meteo"+h).html(climat(meteo[d].hourly[h].weatherCode, meteo[d].hourly[h].isdaytime), h);
```

should be:

```
$("#meteo"+h).html(climat(meteo[d].hourly[h].weatherCode, meteo[d].hourly[h].isdaytime, h));
```

You had `h` as the second argument to `.html()` rather than the third argument to `climat()`. So you were calling `climat()` differently when alerting than when adding the HTML.

Comment: programming at 2AM is not a good idea without glasses :D thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

In your second call to `climat` you are only passing one parameter, in your first call you pass two parameters. In the second call `h` is passed to the `html` function, as this function takes zero or one parameter I assume this is the error.

```
for (h = 1; h < 4; h++) {
    alert(climat(meteo[d].hourly[h].weatherCode, meteo[d].hourly[h].isdaytime, h));
    $("#meteo"+h).html(
        climat(meteo[d].hourly[h].weatherCode, meteo[d].hourly[h].isdaytime),
        h)
}
```

Comment: the problem was a typo, and a simple parentheses made me crazy :D thank you